# Calculate the cumulative distribution function F(X=5).

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

*(Old midterms provided by prof to study)*

I'm struggling to figure out question 9.

My best guess it that it's all the combined probabilities added together before P(X=6), so: 1 - 0.13 = **0.87**. But, as the student who took it got it wrong, I'm not sure. Can someone let me know if I'm right?

If **0.87** is wrong, my other guess is that it would be 0.2 * 5, so **1**.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notation used by the professor for the cumulative distribution function, $$F(X = 5),$$ is very strange and not standard practice in probability theory or statistics.  It is far more common to write $$F_X(5)$$ which is equivalent to $$\Pr[X \le 5],$$ the probability that $X$ is at most $5$.  The notation $$P(X = 4)$$ is common, in fact, more common than the equivalent $\Pr[X = 4]$ which is my personal preference.

Regarding the answer itself, it is obvious that $$F(X = 5) = F_X(5) = \Pr[X \le 5] = 1 - \Pr[X = 6] = 1 - 0.13 = 0.87.$$  This is because we are given the complete probability mass function for $X$ and the event $X \le 5$ is complementary to $X = 6$.

Comment: Thank you! That totally answers my question brilliantly. Quick follow up though.. if the professor was asking for: 0.2 * 5 (the x*f(x) kind of) at X = 5 as the answer, what would that question look like?